# JS - populate an array from another array + modify values

Tags: javascript, arrays

Could someone please help me do the following with JavaScript:

- I have an array (array1) that contains strings
- I need to loop through each element of the initial array (array1)
- then I need to get the value of each index in array1, and add a letter to each value
- and finally to write the modified value of each index from array1 into array2.

Thank you.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Array.map is a good start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//declares the array and initializes it with strings
var array1 = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];

//declares the second array
var array2 = []; 

//this line begins the loop. Everything inside the { } will run once for every single item inside array1
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) 
{
    //this gets the contents of the array at each interval
    var string = array1[i]; 

    //here we take the original string from the array1 and add a letter to it.
    var combo = string + "A"; 

    //this line takes the new string and puts it into the 2nd array
    array2.push(combo); 
}

//displays a message box that shows the contents of the 2nd array
alert(array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Example using Array.map.

```
var singularArray = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Bird'],
pluralArray = singularArray.map(function(value){
    return value+'s';
});

console.log(pluralArray); //Logs ['Dogs', 'Cats', 'Birds']
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fzakf/

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map for details.